Colorful two by two triangles
Turn something colorful into something  white.

                              Y   
                                E B
                                  L
                                  U L
                                R E D O
                                        W
                 
            



The answer is, appropriately for this time of the year,

 Christmas.

The letter grid tells us that:

 The presence of a color in a triangle is related to one of its sides. If the color contains Red, it relates to the horizontal side. If it contains Blue it relates to the vertical side, and if it contains Yellow, it relates to the diagonal side.

For combined colors,

 The two pertinent colors apply: Green is Blue + Yellow, and Purple is Red + Blue.

If we then,

 Mark the lines clued by each triangle's color, we can form the letters for CHRISTMAS left to right, top to bottom.

Visualized:

 


Well done :) If you could just add a visual presentation, to make it easier to follow, that would be great.

Yeah, no clue what you're talking about.

Thanks, much better :)   I might clarify in your second hint though, when  you say 'horizontal side'  I didn't understand...  Also the third hint isn't really 'both', it's something different entirely, which is mentioned for one in hint 2.

Also that things are additive.   It seems like the blue triangles in the second box and eighth box should be purple if not, right?   And the representation in the 4th box is missing some lines.  For the actual puzzle, I think the blues in the 3rd box should be purple to look better.

Give any points for this answer to @Arturo for his great answer, but if you want to figure it out yourself, here's a hint with slightly modified rules that will make it easier to figure out I think:

 

The differences is (spoiler):

 Each color completely defines the criteria.   There is no yellow because it is combined with another color.

